# Why std::move() of a unique_ptr to a void function to reset the pointer takes less time than call explicit unique_ptr.reset()

Tags: c++, memory-management, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I made these PoCs to figure out which is the fastest way to release a unique_ptr memory:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>

void freePointer(std::unique_ptr<int> aPointer){
    // The unique ptr memory is released here
}

int main ()
{
  using namespace std::chrono;

  // POC1
  std::unique_ptr<int> pointer (new int(3));
  high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  pointer.reset();
  high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
  std::cout << "POC1: It took me " << time_span.count() << " seconds." << std::endl;

  // POC2
  std::unique_ptr<int> pointer2 (new int(3));
  high_resolution_clock::time_point t3 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  freePointer(std::move(pointer2));
  high_resolution_clock::time_point t4 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  duration<double> time_span2 = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t4 - t3);
  std::cout << "POC2: It took me " << time_span2.count() << " seconds." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The ouput is:

POC1: It took me 2.573e-06 seconds.
POC2: It took me 5.07e-07 seconds.

There is a magnitude order of difference between the PoX and I'm not understanding the reason.

Could someone give me a light?

Comment: [They compile to identical code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/_3GoxP).

Comment: Microbenchmark issues? One data-point is usually not a good test..

Comment: It's almost certainly noise. Not only is that computation too small to measure with the system clock, the compiler might move the calculation to outside the timer calls because the lines of code don't depend on each other.

Comment: It is really hard to get sub microsecond timing resolution without specialized hardware.

Comment: Reverse the order of the two cases in your code and repeat the test. My guess is that you will get the reversed result. That or you didn't enable optimizations. There really should be no difference at all. For example Clang optimizes the whole `std::unique_ptr` and the object it manages away, so there is nothing left between the timer calls, see https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/PoWkRC.

Comment: did you compile with optimizations on?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <ratio>
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

void freePointer(std::unique_ptr<int> aPointer){
    // The unique ptr memory is released here
}

int main ()
{
  using namespace std::chrono;

  // POC1
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> pointers;
  for(int i=0;i<10000;++i) {
      pointers.emplace_back(new int(3));
  }
  high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  for(int i=0;i<10000;++i) {
      pointers[i].reset();
  }
  high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  duration<double> time_span = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t2 - t1);
  std::cout << "POC1: It took me " << time_span.count() << " seconds." << std::endl;
  
  // POC2
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> pointers2;
  for(int i=0;i<10000;++i) {
      pointers2.emplace_back(new int(3));
  }
  high_resolution_clock::time_point t3 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  for(int i=0;i<10000;++i) {
        freePointer(std::move(pointers2[i]));
  }
  high_resolution_clock::time_point t4 = high_resolution_clock::now();
  duration<double> time_span2 = duration_cast<duration<double>>(t4 - t3);
  std::cout << "POC2: It took me " << time_span2.count() << " seconds." << std::endl;
  
  return 0;
}
```

After testing it in an [online compiler](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c++_compiler) the results show that POC2 is slower
But the result are inconclusive as there were situations were POC1 was slower.

POC1: It took me 0.000578603 seconds.
POC2: It took me 0.00146163 seconds.

For a single run is you replace the order, first POC2 and then POC1 the second one will be the slowest.